# How to Avoid Constraint SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have a problem. i got 2 tables, with 1 foreign key.

Table A and Table B

```
CREATE TABLE A
kdtrans int (5) primary key



INSERT INTO A Values
(1),(2),(3)
```

then i want to insert in table B

```
CREATE TABLE B
kdtrans int (5) primary key,
FOREIGN KEY kdtrans REFERENCES A(kdtrans)



INSERT INTO B Values
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)
```

these query is error cause of constraint. so what should i do to avoid constraint. i wont to insert new record in table A.

Comment: Why do you want to insert records into `B` that violate the constraint? The whole point of having constraints is to prevent this.

Comment: cause the boss ask me to do ):

Comment: Drop the constraint then.

Comment: if i drop the constraint, foreign key doesn't follow to drop ?

Comment: no fields will be dropped if you drop a constraint, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do this by disabling the constraint but you might as well just drop it as the thing it is supposed to guarantee is no longer true.

To disable the constraint you can use

```
CREATE TABLE A
  (
     kdtrans INT PRIMARY KEY
  )

INSERT INTO A
VALUES      (1),
            (2),
            (3)

CREATE TABLE B
  (
     kdtrans INT PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT FK FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES A(kdtrans)
  )

ALTER TABLE B
  NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK

INSERT INTO B
VALUES      (1),
            (2),
            (3),
            (4),
            (5)
```

To drop it you would use

```
ALTER TABLE B DROP CONSTRAINT FK
```